# Force instantiate related object in dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have a dagger module to provide an instance :

```
@Binds
abstract MyInterface provideMyInterface(MyInterfaceImpl impl);
```

When an instance of `MyInterfaceImpl` is created, I also want to instantiate an instance of another class automatically. Lets say we call it `MySupportingInstance`.

How do I make sure `MySupportingInstance` is also instantiated when `MyInterfaceImpl` is instantiated. I can inject `MySupportingInstance` in `MyInterfaceImpl` to achieve this. But the latter does not use the reference, so it weird that it injects and does not use the reference.

Is there a way my module can take care of this ?

Comment: Why does MySupportingInstance have to start existing at the same time? Why wouldn't you just inject MySupportingInstance when you need it, have it depend on MyInterfaceImpl if it does depend on that class, and create MyInterfaceImpl at that time if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can add scopes to objects, it would force dagger to hold references internally, and then do

```
@Provides
public static MyInterface provideMyInterface(
    MyInterfaceImpl impl, MySupportingInstance instance) {
  // Forced to create an instance of MySupportingInstance, but returning just
  // MyInterfaceImpl.
  // If objects are scoped, instance, once created, will be hold internally by
  // Dagger.
  return impl;
}
```